# c++ extract just numbers from an ostringstream

Tags: c++, string, ostringstream

If I have an `ostringstream` that contains various numbers separated by `-`

(That's: `space` `-` `space` btw)

Could I extract each number individually?

Comment: Yes, you could.

Comment: Simplest way: Whenever there is a `-` character expected, extract it into a dummy string object that is ignored.

Comment: If you could submit that as an answer luk32, I'd gladly accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use one of spiting functions from here: 
[Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)
storing them as strings inside std::vector, 
then use std::stoi (or equivalent) which parses string to integer , surrounding each call with try / catch.

example (after splitting):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.size(); i++)
{
    try
    {
        int myInt = std::stoi(arrayOfStrings[i]);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout<<e.what()<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work....

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
std::vector<int> ints;
boost::split(ints, " - ",std::stoi (stream.str()));
```

Comment: That's assuming I'm using Boost

Comment: picky... your question did not mentioned not using boost... :p

Comment: I would have thought I needn't have specified everything I am not using, for that list would rather vast.

Comment: @fakeaccount a simple "using only the standard library" would have covered it.

Comment: Nevertheless, assumed knowledge is the worst kind of knowledge.